# I want to create ads with dot navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH9h8.jpg

What is this called? How to implement it in app using kotlin?
I want it to navigate automatically after specific time like in amazon.

Comment: Do you mean you want like 5 ads like this and have them slide over and over again?

Comment: Yes @RahulRawat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are referring to here is just images autoscrolling using a [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask) inside a recyclerview with a [PagerSnapHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/PagerSnapHelper).